# Wireless-tools for linux to scan for wireless devices without them being connected

Tags: c, linux, wireless

Is it possible to use a WiFi router to simply scan for existing wireless-capable devices (e.g. smartphones) which have Wi-Fi enabled on scanning mode, but are not connected to anyone.

My ultimate goal is using OpenWrt on a TP-Link wireless router and scanning for mobile phone devices in the surrounding area.

So can it be done without them connecting to the device? Using wireless-tools, libiw library?

Thanks

Comment: It is basically all devices known to access points are determined using Probe requests, thus if no device is connected to AP, then you cannot know that they are having wireless card -- If this is what you are asking

Comment: Yes I would like to know if it possible to "see" the devices in range which even though are capable of connecting to an AP (me) they are not. So you're saying they need to connect to me first before I can see that they exist... The reverse can't happen? Sending out a probe from the AP to devices in proximity?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is called "passive scanning". The de-facto standard Linux utility for this is [Kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/), your distribution's package manager likely has a package. Depending on your used hardware it may even work in parallel to acting as a regular router. However mose W-LAN interfaces can not operate in passive mode and master mode at the same time.

Answer (score -6):

The following tools are available

1. NetworkManager
2. wicd

Adding another Answer:
You can use the following command also

```
iwlist wlan0 scanning
```

It gives lot of information about all the wireless networks available in your range... the sample output is also given here

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 00:1F:E6:00:48:12
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"BrcmAP0"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001fc005bb183
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1562ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00074272636D415030
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AFC191BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B081500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180201F02C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 02 - Address: D0:DF:C7:91:2B:18
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=35/70  Signal level=-75 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"SuriyhaSri"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000002313fb5ce
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1714ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000A53757269796861537269
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B0C12961824
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B1B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

Comment: Do these provide wireless devices (e.g. a smartphone with WiFi switched on, NOT access points) information?

Comment: @bubbly What is the OS you are using and what is the Desktop environment

Comment: OpenWrt on the device, and Ubuntu 12.04 on desktop environment